# Spring boot version 3.0.0 springdoc-openapi-ui dont work

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

open api dependencies

[image: 1]

spring boot version

[image: 2]

I try to enable swagger openapi springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.14 but unfortunately I can not make that, when i try to access http://localhost:8182/swagger-ui/ I get error 404. My question is should i change the version of spring boot ?

Answer (score 2):

You're importing Springdoc 1, which is only compatible with Spring Boot 2.

For Spring Boot 3, you need to use [Springdoc 2](https://springdoc.org/v2/).

The correct gradle import is:

```
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2")
```